# improve performance of searching in varchar fields

Tags: php, mysql, performance

with every new visit from a search engine, I save the keyword (e.g. "php performance") the visitor searched for at the search engine.

To count the number how often the keyword is used per day, I need to check whether somebody else already searched for the term that specific day.

After several months the table gets very big and the mysql check for the existence of the keyword that day takes longer and longer. So I switched to an extra table where I only save the keyword and give each keyword a specific ID to only have the checking process once and not each new day. This specific ID which I related to the keyword I insert in the table with diversification for each day.

This already works better but this table also gets bigger and bigger...

Does somebody has a good solution for this to higher performance?

Best,

Freddy

Comment: Why don't you use an existing solution like google analytics, or Piwik, or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to performance there are some *'tricks'* one can do to improve:

1. Build a caching mechanism. That is what you already did by making a second table. You could take that further and keep the cached table in memory or memcached.
2. Opimize your queries, and make sure there are **indexes** on the search field(s). Not shure if you did that.
3. Try to **(de)normalize** your database. Sometimes a different database structure is not optimal from a design point, but optimized for speed. Not sure if you did that.
4. Look at different solutions for searching, perhaps have a look at [Lucene](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/techniques/lucene-php.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a question to 2.: Is it possible to index a varchar field by mysql?

Comment: Sure, just add a index like with any other field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't save all keywords typed by users to DB. Make a table with columns: keyword, counter

Each time visitor enters the keyword, you search fo the keyword in DB and increase the counter, if the keyword doesn't exist then create new one with counter=1.

Also use index on keyword column and DO NOT USE FULLTEXT search, use straight comparision:

```
SELECT counter FROM keyword_table WHERE keyword="exact keyword" LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I nearly did this with the extra table but I still have the problem that the mysql query searches in a varchar field and this takes quite time for 100000 entries.

Comment: Try using char type instead of varchar, it takes more space than varchar but its faster in searches. It shouldn't be slow for 100k entries, maybe you are doing something wrong in app logic.

Comment: i just run the sql in phpmyadmin and it says that it takes 0.10 seconds.

Comment: Is this query being executed on each page visit?If not then it's ultra fast, but if does then use temporary table to store keywords and use cron job to run query which will merge temporary table with final table and truncate the temporary one.

Comment: no not on each page visit, only the first time the user comes to the website from a search engine where the q= variable is net in the referrer. I now set an index to the varchar field and it works fine now! it only takes 0.001 seconds ..

Answer (score 0):

I personally wouldn't use MySQL as the primary backing store for this data, I would look to much faster and more highly available NoSQL solutions, perhaps using MySQL as a backup store ...

With APC there are built in mutex locks and I don't think that your number would get corrupted, if you get apc up and running and aren't happy with it's counts, you need direct access to Mutex so that no serving process may write at the same time as another, Mutex are provided in my pthreads project which can be found https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads, need any more help feel free to ask ...